# Mat Tabs (Angular 10)

Tags: angular, router

**Tengo un tab de Angular Material, necesito que al entrar a un una url, al salir de allí me direccione a un tab en especifico, si alguien puede colaborarme con eso, estaré muy agradecido**

Comment: Añade lo que has intentado. Y sé un poco más explicativo. [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Como preguntar StackOverFlow
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)